# Delta is growing instead of going down in simple one neuron neural network

Tags: python, neural-network

Trying to implement simple neural network using Delta rule without step function having almost no experience in programming and machine learning. So far I have next code.

```
%matplotlib inline
from random import choice 
from numpy import array, dot, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
training_data = [(array([20,10,1]), 10), 
             (array([10,12,1]), 8), 
             (array([11,20,1]), 5), 
             (array([13,16,1]), 9), ]
w = random.rand(3)
a = []
mu = 0.001
n = 50
for i in xrange(n): 
    x, expected = choice(training_data)
    result = dot(w,x)
    delta = abs(expected - result)
    a.append(delta)
    if delta < a[-1]:
        w += mu * delta * x
    else: w -= mu * delta * x
plt.plot(a)
```

The problem with this code is that the delta rule is growing up instead of going down.[You may see that from this graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCe7S.png) I am not sure where I made a mistake with it. Any help is appreciated.

**EDITED VERSION OF MY FOR LOOP**

```
for i in xrange(n): 
x, expected = choice(training_data)
result = dot(w,x)
delta = abs(expected - result)
if delta < a[-1]:
    w += mu * delta * x
else: w -= mu * delta * x
a.append(delta)
```

also, I have stated a=[0]. [new results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWXEU.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you append `delta` to the end of `a`, then compare `delta` to the last element of `a` (`a[-1]`), you are comparing `delta < delta`, and this branch will never be visited.

Comment: thanx, dumb me :) I am now thinking how to compare those starting from the second iteration?

Comment: I have moved  a.append(delta) to the bottom and changed a = [] to a = [0], but stil, the effect is the same.

Comment: This results suggests that one of your conditions (< or > a[-1]) is always satisfied : `expected` and `x` are constant, so to have a big `delta`, `result` has to grow, so `w` has to continue growing. Think about why a new delta is always bigger than the previous one. `print()` helps a lot when debugging code ! Also, try reversing the inequality, just to see.